# Dealing with FileReader and subString

Tags: java, substring, filereader

I'm trying to read a file `.txt` which contains 8 lines of Stores in different regions. Each line has 15 characters. When I run this code, just the first line is printed and afterwards it throws this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 10
    at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1951)
```

```java
String line = "";
String region = "", name = "";
BufferedReader file = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Stores.txt"));
line = file.readLine();
while (line != null) {
    region = line.substring(0, 10);
    name = line.substring(10);
    line = file.readLine();
    System.out.println("" + region + name);
}
file.close();
```

File:

```
Montrèal   16890

New York   27659

Pittsburg  26657

California 11201

Virginia   32945

Seattle    33981

Colorado   10345
```

Comment: Please post the contents of the text file too.

Comment: Did you try debugging your code? Are you sure that each line contains at least 10 characters? Aren't there empty lines (for instance at the end of file)?

Comment: Your file seems to have empty lines between lines with text. You need to skip parsing part on that lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't skip over the empty lines. Try this one:

```
String line = "";
String region = "", name = "";
BufferedReader file = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Stores.txt"));
line = file.readLine();
while (line != null) {
    if (!line.isEmpty()) {
        region = line.substring(0, 10);
        name = line.substring(10);
        System.out.println("" + region + name);
    }
    line = file.readLine();
}
file.close();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't know that there was this Method for strings.

Comment: You're welcome. You could also have a look at the method String.split which you could use to split your String into two parts without being dependent on a concrete position. For example: line.split(" "); would create an array with two elements, your region and the zip code.

Answer (score 1):

I've checked the length of the line before substring

```
String line = "";
String region = "", name = "";
BufferedReader file = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Stores.txt"));
line = file.readLine();
while (line != null) {
    if (!line.isEmpty()&&line.length() >= 15) {
        region = line.substring(0, 10);
        name = line.substring(10);
        line = file.readLine();
        System.out.println("" + region + name);
    }
}
file.close();
```

Comment: This won't help since when you encounter an empty line, the next line is not read.

Comment: Now I've checked that part too

Comment: This is also correct as long as I'm trying to find a way to specifically use the lines with 15 characters or more. Thanks Madhan!